# Can we have two FullTrust Permissions in a UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, console-application, desktop-bridge

I am developing a UWP app wherein I have created a UWP project, Windows Packaging project, Class library, console application(windows application).

Here the UWP app communicates with the console app(win23) by sending request and getting responses from the methods created in the Win32 app. This is done by using FullTrust permission.

But, now I want to add another Fulltrust permission app in this project that will run independently whenever i call this app. Also, these two win32 apps will not have any user interface but will only acts as a background process. So in the new win32 I am implementing the functionality where I am accessing my Microsoft Office outlook contacts.

So If I declare this new win32 app in the Package.manifest file of the Packaging project and run the app. It gives me an error saying We can have only one fullTrust permission in the project.

Please can you guide me how to go about this.

Comment: Hi, For now, you can only have one FullTrust program in your project. Please consider combining the two programs you use into one.

Comment: Thanks, but my previous win32 app does completely different functionality and it occupies memory that will be more compared to the new win32 app

Comment: If you don't use the specific win32 features, I suggest you use the [Windows Runtime Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/), you can create a [background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) for your app.

Answer (score 0):

While you can have only a single fulltrust process extension declared in the manifest, you can certainly launch as many full trust processes as you like. The way to do this is by creating a launcher process and declare that as your fulltrust process extension. From that launcher you can then launch any number of other EXEs depending on a parameter that you pass to the launcher.

This approach is explained in detail here with complete sample code:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/

For completeness: another option (more complex and maybe not what you want) is to declare multiple  objects in your manifest. The additional  objects can be fulltrust applications that you launch from your UWP via the AppListEntry API.